OC4 4.14.x supported Camel-K 2.0.1?
we needed to upgrade OC4 14.14.x  so we needed to check if  Camel-K  2.0.1 is supported by OCP 4.14.x or not
and how find matrix between OCP and Camel-K because I'm not found this matrix in my search
can you help me to answer question.

Camel K has not a direct compatibility mapping with Openshift documented. However you can check the compatibility API by checking at the project go.mod file. For example, on latest main development (future 2.4) it supports Openshift 4.15
As for version 2.0.1, you can see the API was set for 3.9.1. However I think that it should work OOTB even with newer versions of Openshift.
